# I'm looking at the lambda log

Tags: node.js, lambda

I'm looking at the lambda log

There is a place to log in the callback of s3.putObject, but this part is not visible.

In my local it works fine.

```
const uploadParams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key, Body: fileStream};
console.log('5. ');
await s3.upload(uploadParams, (err: any, data: any) => {
    console.log('7. s3.putObject callback function');
    if (data) {
        console.log("Upload Success", data);
    } else if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
});
console.log('6. ');
```

no 7. s3.putObject callback function

[image]

Comment: `s3.upload` BOTH takes a callback and is async? That seems very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `putObject` instead of `upload` and remove `: any` parts in the callback.

```
const uploadParams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key, Body: fileStream};
putObject(uploadParams, (err, data) => {
  console.log('7. s3.putObject callback function');
  if (data) {
      console.log("Upload Success", data);
  } else if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
  }
})
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property